# Dynamically executing a <script> tag with an external src attribute using eval

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using the [Genius API](https://docs.genius.com/) to retrieve the lyrics for a given song and embed them within an HTML `<div>` tag. I'm interacting with this API using PHP, via an AJAX GET request.

In the event of a successful AJAX request, I retrieve the following HTML from my PHP:

```
<div id='rg_embed_link_2351532' class='rg_embed_link' data-song-id='2351532'>
    Read <a href='https://genius.com/The-1975-the-sound-lyrics'>“The Sound” by The 1975</a> on Genius
</div> 
<script crossorigin src='//genius.com/songs/2351532/embed.js'></script>
```

The script tag returned by the Genius API will embed the lyrics and lyric information when executed.

I'm attempting to import this HTML into my already existing `<div>`. In this case, the `<script>` portion will not be executed. I've tried to use an `eval()` within the 'success' function of my AJAX to dynamically execute this script, but I'm having no success:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'lyrics.php',
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    success: function(success){
        geniusHTML = success;

        //Insert geniusHTML including script tag into div
        var lyricsDiv = document.getElementById("lyricsDiv");
        lyricsDiv.innerHTML = geniusHTML;

        //Get the script tag from the html and use eval on it
        var innerScript = lyricsDiv.getElementsByTagName('script')
        eval(innerScript.outerHTML);
    }
});
```

I've tried to eval the:

- `.outerHTML` -- The console shows this value to be: `<script crossorigin="" src="//genius.com/songs/2351532/embed.js"></script>`
- `.innerHTML` -- Attribute appears to be empty.
- `.src` -- The console shows this value to be: `http://genius.com/songs/2351532/embed.js`. The`eval()` function errors on this with `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`.

I feel I am potentially doing this backward. Should I execute the script from my AJAX return *before* I add it to the div? (The script generates quite a few embed div tags)

**EDIT**

With instruction from answerer *Sjoerd de Wit*, I attempted to create a new script tag from the source tag's `src` attribute, and add it via document.head.appendChild. This did not work, providing the warning:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write
>   into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless
>   it is explicitly opened.

Comment: `eval()` == `evil()`. Do not use it. You can read everywhere over the internet why it's bad to use it.

Comment: @MarkBaijens Noted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**
Answering my own question.

The other answers to this question are perfectly acceptable and work in most situations. However, if the external .js file contains a **document.write** within it, your browser will give you the following warnings:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

One of the ways to get around this is to use [**Postscribe**](https://github.com/krux/postscribe). Postscribe will override any instances of document.write within javascript passed to it.

In the context of my code -- which, rest assured, I will refactor to make it more efficient -- I retrieve my script tag from my div by getting the outerHTML of the element, then I pass it into postscribe.

With this use case, postscribe takes two arguments; the div to pass the script to, and the script itself. Of course -- you can pass the script inline or via a variable as I have done in the below example:

```
var myScript = myDiv.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].outerHTML;
postscribe('#myDiv', myScript);
```

Please see the postscribe documentation linked above for installation instructions and further functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You should get the src from the script tag and dynamically create and load it in your html

```
var script = document.createElement("script");  
var innerScript = lyricsDiv.getElementsByTagName('script')
script.src = innerScript.src; 

document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! This did not work for a script containing an embed -- please see warning that I posted in post edit.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Baijens, this explains the warning. I don't think I can refactor the script as it is provided by Genius, but I'll try postscribe as mentioned in answers. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery's `.html()` instead of javascript's `.innerHTML()` will automatically evaluate scripts inside the string

so, try to change this line

```
//Insert geniusHTML including script tag into div
var lyricsDiv = document.getElementById("lyricsDiv");
lyricsDiv.innerHTML = geniusHTML;

//Get the script tag from the html and use eval on it
var innerScript = lyricsDiv.getElementsByTagName('script')
eval(innerScript.outerHTML);
```

into

```
$("#lyricsDiv").html(geniusHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks scott - this works but I'm still getting the warning mentioned in my EDIT. However this warning seems to be a separate issue related to `document.write`.
Accepting this as best answer in this context.